# firestore, do I need to enable persistence in order to trigger listener locally?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

according to this [video](https://youtu.be/oDvdAFP6OhQ?t=538), at 8:58, Todd say:

> when you write to document, the change is made locally and trigger any
> real-time listeners on that document

pretty convenient for UI update

my question is, do I need to enable [persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence) in order to trigger listener locally?

because it is not enabled on web by default due to security issue and I don't feel like want to enable it

Comment: Answer below. If you're having trouble making this work, edit your question to show the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firestore SDK always fires events for operations that are made in the client. You don't need to enable disk persistence for that.